# How to communicate between Music Playback Service and UI Thread

Tags: android, android-service

I have got a list of Music Titles in a ListView.

I can click on each item to play the Music through a MediaPlayer in a Service.

Now I want to implement 2 Features:

- Music ProgressBar which is showing the current position in the song
- The service shall continue playing when Song is over with the next song in the list

So how can I update the UI from a background service?
(I know there are some solutions on Stackoverflow but they seem to me a little bit of an overkill to send a Broadcast each Second from the Service i.e.)
Do I have to use Binding? What is the benefit of Binding?
Right now I just start the service with an Intent (startService(intent)) which contains the Song path.

What about the 2nd question? How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you built the service by yourself. Thus you know how it is built and how to get access to a mediaPlayer reference. What you need to do is to transform your service into a [bound service.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html) Maybe you will want your service to be started via `startService` (otherwise the bound service won't survive your activity), but afterwards, you will have to bind to it from inside your activity.

Once you are bound, you will get a [IBinder](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html#Binder) (that you will define) and will be able to export the mediaPlayer reference to the bound activity through this IBinder. Afterwards, everything is quite straightforward, plug a listener on the media player and update your UI (in the UI thread !).

Also, you will need your [service to be put forward](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html#Foreground).

Comment: But I read about Binding that the service will be destroyed once I leave the app. But I do want the music still playing, unless I click stop in the app.

Comment: no, bound services are destroyed when the activity exits only if you start the service by binding to it. If you start the service via startService, then it will have a lifecycle that is independent of the activity that binds to it. Read the docs, everything in it.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html. First 2 paragraphs

Comment: Thanks! Do you have a Tutorial or Example App that shows binding (maybe in a music context?)

Comment: And how would you do the update of the ProgressBar? Shall I make a loop: while playing check binder.mediaplayer.currentposition -  or something like that?

Comment: don't loop, register a listener on the media player. Oh, no, never loop ! And sorry, but I don't have such a precise tutorial. Just follow the tracks I gave you, it's a good starting point, really.

Comment: Okay, one last thing and I will try it:
Where do I have to implement the listener in the Activity(would make sense so that I can directly update the UI) or in the Service (but then I have to periodically check for a variable that holds the currentpos...)? What kind of Listener is it ( I cant find an appropriate one)?

Comment: From within the activity, bind your service through a binder. The binder will have a method like getMediaPlayer. Then your activity will get a reference on the player and will add a listener (which I assume will be an inner class of the activity because, as you said, it's easier to update the UI from within the activity.

Comment: Hi, I am making a music player. I have setup a bind service(which is initially started by startService).In my Service I have a 'onSeekCompleteListener' to tell me when to play the next Song.Should I plugin another listener in my activity(to update UI)? As I understand that's what you said in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was solving very similar issues, however, I did the mixing/playing part myself.
The code for the android player-service part is at [-github-](https://github.com/josef-jelinek/tiny-mod-player/tree/master/app.gamod-player/src/gamod/client)

For communication between application and the service (it should be a foreground service with a notification in status bar, otherwise it can be silently killed / paused quite frequently) I experimented with different approaches and ended up with

- Activity -> Service - using Messenger
- Service -> Activity / anything - using BroadcastReceiver

The code on github is not too big (less than 500 lines total including imports) to give you an inspiration...

Btw. it also shows a service binding that does not kill service on activity exit.